# Fastest way to map multiple character columns to numerical values

Tags: r, join, dplyr, data.table

I have an algorithm that at each iteration calculates means for certain groups (the groups do not change only their values).

The table of the values -

```
d1 <- data.frame(x = sample(LETTERS, N, replace = TRUE), 
                  y1=rnorm(N))
head(d1)
#   x         y1
# 1 H -0.7852538
# 2 G -0.6739159
# 3 V -1.7783771
# 4 L -0.2849846
# 5 I -0.1760284
# 6 V -0.2785826
```

I can calculate the means (in several ways: dplyr, data.table and tapply). I have another data.frame consisting of two columns with the group names.

```
d2 <- data.frame('group.high' = sample(LETTERS, N * 2, replace = TRUE), 
                 'group.low' = sample(LETTERS, N * 2, replace = TRUE))
head(d2)
#   group.high group.low
# 1          U         L
# 2          K         J
# 3          C         Q
# 4          Q         A
# 5          Q         U
# 6          K         W
```

I want to add to columns, `mean.high` and `mean.better`, of the mean values of each group based on `d1`.

So far I have tried two options from `dplyr` and `data.table`. I had to use left_join twice in either of them. They are both similar in speed.

```
microbenchmark(
  dplyr = {
  means <- tapply(d1$y1, INDEX = d1$x, FUN = mean)
  ### Solution 1 
  dplyr.d2 <- left_join(d2,data.frame('group.high' = names(means), 
                                      'mean.high' = means, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ) %>%  
    left_join(., data.frame('group.low' = names(means), 
                            'mean.low' = means, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))},
  data.table = {
  ### Solution 2 
  d1    <- as.data.table(d1)
  d2    <- as.data.table(d2)
  means <- d1[ ,.(means = mean(y1)), by = x]
  new.d2 <- data.table::merge.data.table(x = d2, y = means, by.x = 'group.high', by.y = 'x')
  data.table.d2 <- data.table::merge.data.table(x = new.d2, y = means, by.x = 'group.low', by.y = 'x')
  }
)

Unit: milliseconds
       expr     min       lq     mean  median       uq      max neval cld
      dplyr 34.0837 36.88650 53.22239 42.9227 47.50660 231.5066   100  a 
 data.table 40.2071 47.70735 87.46804 51.2517 59.05385 258.4999   100   b
```

Is there a better way? How can I speed the calculation?

As mentioned in the comments, there is an iterative process of updating the values. Here is an example.

```
N <- 10000

iterFuncDplyr <- function(d1, d2) { 
  dplyr.d2 <- left_join(d2,data.frame('group.high' = names(means), 
                                      'mean.high' = means, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ) %>%  
    left_join(., data.frame('group.low' = names(means), 
                            'mean.low' = means, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))
  return(var(d1$y1))
}

iterFuncData <- function(d1, d2) { 
  means <- d1[ ,.(means = mean(y1)), by = x]
  new.d2 <- data.table:::merge.data.table(x = d2, y = means, by.x = 'group.high', by.y = 'x')
  data.table.d2 <- data.table:::merge.data.table(x = new.d2, y = means, by.x = 'group.low', by.y = 'x')
  return(var(d1$y1))
}


d1 <- data.frame(x = sample(LETTERS, N, replace = TRUE), 
                 y1=rnorm(N))

d2 <- data.frame('group.high' = sample(LETTERS, N * 2, replace = TRUE), 
                 'group.low' = sample(LETTERS, N * 2, replace = TRUE))

library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(dplyr = {
temp.val <- 0 

for (i in 1:10) {
  d1$y1 <- temp.val + rnorm(N)
  temp.val <- iterFuncDplyr(d1, d2)
}},
data.table = {
d1    <- as.data.table(d1)
d2    <- as.data.table(d2)

temp.val <- 0 

for (i in 1:10) {
  d1$y1 <- temp.val + rnorm(N)
  temp.val <- iterFuncData(d1, d2)
}
}
)

Unit: milliseconds
       expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
      dplyr 46.22904 50.67959 52.78275 51.96358 53.34825 108.2874   100
 data.table 63.81111 67.13257 70.85537 69.85712 72.72446 127.4228   100
```

Comment: What do you want `N` set at for your dataframes?

Comment: N = 10,000 seems reasonable.

Comment: Are you doing this repeatedly? When you say "the groups do not change only their values", it makes me think that a `data.table` will be fastest if you set key. Setting the key for `d1` will be a little expensive the first time, but will drastically speed up all future iterations.

Comment: Gregor, yes exactly. I'm just not that familiar with the `data.table` (especially not as I should be).

Comment: Additionally, I don't know how the values change each iteration, but `data.table` will be faster at that as well...

Comment: Could you clarify what changes at each iteration? My impression is that the `y1` column of `d1` changes, but `d1$x` stays the same. Does `d2` change at each iteration? Are you adding new columns to `d2` every iteration, or just updating `mean.high` and `mean.better` each time?

Comment: Yes. `y1` changes, `d1$x` stays the same. `d2` does not change except for the addition of the columns.

Comment: Do new columns get added to d2 every time, so there are more columns each iteration? Or do the 2 columns `mean.high` and `mean.better` get updated each time?

Comment: Really, if would help if you would update the example to do, say, 5 iterations. Then we could benchmark on that process. Perhaps illustrate with a small N = 10 example, but when we get into benchmarks we can bump up to N = 10000.

Comment: ‘y1’ is changed at each iteration and based on it ‘mean.high’ and ‘mean.low’ are updated (not added).

Comment: I have added an example of the iterative process.

Comment: In general, the `dx    <- as.data.table(dx)` calls are inefficient/not recommended. Just do `setDT(dx)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could subset the named vector `means` to create new columns and match your output:

```
means <- tapply(d1$y1, INDEX = d1$x, FUN = mean)
d2$mean.high <- means[d2$group.high]
d2$mean.low <- means[d2$group.low]

identical(as.matrix(d2), as.matrix(d3)) #factor vs character, used d3 w/ benchmark
[1] TRUE

Unit: microseconds
       expr    min      lq      mean   median       uq     max neval
      dplyr 4868.2 5316.25  5787.123  5524.15  5892.70 12187.3   100
 data.table 8254.4 9606.60 10438.424 10118.35 10771.75 20966.5   100
     subset  481.2  529.40   651.194   550.35   582.55  7849.9   100
```

**Benchmark code**:

```
d3 <- d2

microbenchmark::microbenchmark( # N = 10000
  dplyr = {
    means <- tapply(d1$y1, INDEX = d1$x, FUN = mean)
    ### Solution 1 
    dplyr.d2 <- left_join(d2,data.frame('group.high' = names(means), 
                                        'mean.high' = means, stringsAsFactors = FALSE) ) %>%  
      left_join(., data.frame('group.low' = names(means), 
                              'mean.low' = means, stringsAsFactors = FALSE))},
  data.table = {
    ### Solution 2 
    d1    <- as.data.table(d1)
    d2    <- as.data.table(d2)
    means <- d1[ ,.(means = mean(y1)), by = x]
    new.d2 <- data.table::merge.data.table(x = d2, y = means, by.x = 'group.high', by.y = 'x')
    data.table.d2 <- data.table::merge.data.table(x = new.d2, y = means, by.x = 'group.low', by.y = 'x')
  },
  subset = {
    means <- tapply(d1$y1, INDEX = d1$x, FUN = mean)
    d3$mean.high <- means[d2$group.high]
    d3$mean.low <- means[d2$group.low]

  }
)
```

Comment: I came up with a very similar method but using `data.table` and it seems it needs N to be a lot bigger than 10,000 before it becomes faster.

Comment: @sindri_baldur, personally, I would love to see it as an answer if you have the time. I imagine it could be useful for those in the future who come across this question and have N > 10,000. I'll update my benchmark later today to include more iterations using `replicate`, too.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an answer very similar to Andrew's but relying on `data.table` instead of `tapply()` (which seems faster for very big `N`).

```
library(data.table)
# Create a named vector "means"
means <- setDT(d1)[, mean(y1), by = x][, setNames(V1, x)]
setDT(d2)[, c("mean.high.means", "mean.low.means") := 
              .(means[as.character(group.high)], means[as.character(group.low)])]
```

Output:

```
        group.high group.low mean.high.means mean.low.means
     1:          Z         W     0.017032792   0.0091625547
     2:          A         A     0.013796137   0.0137961371
     3:          V         S    -0.011570159   0.0004560325
     4:          D         X     0.005475629   0.0200984250
     5:          U         H    -0.008249901   0.0054537833
    ---                                                    
199996:          H         K     0.005453783   0.0079905631
199997:          A         T     0.013796137  -0.0068537963
199998:          W         U     0.009162555  -0.0082499015
199999:          T         V    -0.006853796  -0.0115701585
200000:          G         J     0.014829259   0.0206598470
```

Reproducible data:

```
N = 1e5
set.seed(1) 
d1 <- data.frame(
  x  = sample(LETTERS, N, replace = TRUE), 
  y1 = rnorm(N)
) 
d2 <- data.frame(
  group.high = sample(LETTERS, N * 2, replace = TRUE), 
  group.low  = sample(LETTERS, N * 2, replace = TRUE)
)
```